# CPU, RAM and FSB frequency

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, bios, underclock

I built my own PC out of parts from the internet.

- Motherboard: Asrock G41C-S - [motherboard specs](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/G41C-S/)
- CPU: Intel Pentium Dual Core E5700 3GHz
- GPU: AMD Sapphire Radeon HD 7500 1GB GDDR5
- My old RAM is 1 x Nanya 2GB DDR3 and 1 x Apacer 2GB DDR3
- My new RAM is 2 x Kingston HyperX Fury 4GB DDR3 1600Mhz - [new RAM specs](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/HX316C10FB_4.pdf)

The problem is when I use my new RAM the PC will turn on, but without any video. If I use one old RAM and one new RAM, I can go into the BIOS and see that only my old RAM is recognized and not my new RAM.

My motherboard only supports DDR3 up to 1333MHz, but I read on the Internet that RAM can be under-clocked to match the motherboard settings, well that didn't work for me.

The BIOS is on default settings. How can I get it to work?

Comment: *The problem is when I use my new RAM the PC will turn on, but it won't boot*. - What do you mean when you say - *won't boot*

Comment: When i turn on the PC with ONLY the new RAM installed it does turn on but there is no video signal (my monitor says DVI no signal and VGA no signal) and i don't see the BIOS startup screen nor Windows 10 loading screen. If i want it to turn on i can only change the new RAM with the old one :/

Answer (score 1):

Your new Kingston RAM is single sided [per the spec](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/HX316C10FB_4.pdf).

`Height 1.291” (32.80mm) w/heatsink, single sided component`

All 4GB RAM listed in the memory [QVL list](http://www.asrock.com/mb/memory/G41C-S.pdf) listed are double-sided.

A quick google search gives me the [result](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/support/faq_content.php?S_ID=579). So its a hardware limit. You need a double-sided 4GB RAM to work on the motherboard.

> Will Intel G41 chipset motherboard support single side 4GB memory
>   module?
>
> Due to chipset support limitation, Intel G41 chipset
>   motherboard will not be able to support single side 4GB memory
>   modules. System will not boot up properly when use single side 4GB
>   memory.

Comment: So if i'm going to choose a double-sided 8Gb Kingston RAM stick which is running at 1333Mhz which can be found here: (http://www.emag.ro/memorie-kingston-8gb-ddr3-1333mhz-non-ecc-cl9-1-5v-kvr1333d3n9-8g/pd/EBQRDBBBM/?ref=smart-history_1&recid=idsm3kue-56v87bvjt16-C.c17_a187.S.VP_AP_VIS.U.273810-09c2sic) it should work ?

Comment: No, 8GB single stick wouldn't work. You need a double-sided 4GB stick(and x2 for 8GB total)

Comment: I found a kit of 2x 4Gb Corsair DDR3 1333Mhz RAM here: (http://www.emag.ro/kit-corsair-4gb-2-x-2gb-ddr3-1333mhz-cmv4gx3m2a1333c9/pd/EQMD2BBBM/?tree_ref=28( I think this will work.

Comment: its a 2x2GB kits, 2GB each, 4GB total, same as your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

I actually returned the RAM kit and got my money back. The RAM wasn't working with the MOBO i had anyway :/ Upgraded my CPU and MOBO and now they actually work but i'm using the old RAM now.